# Block Level Scope Access In JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know that you will think this is a duplicate, yet all I have found through the many related posts is that people flood each one with uneducated "No's", which I am very glad has not yet happened here. Either way, I would like to re-open this discussion.

Lets take, for example, the "not-well-known" `let` statement:

```
function foo()
{
    var bar = 5;

    if(true)
    {
        let bar = 10;
        alert(bar);
    }

    alert(bar);
}
```

This function will first alert `10` and then alert `5`.

This is because `bar = 5` is on the **function level scope** while the reassignment of `bar = 10` is only retained within the **block level scope**, thanks to our little buddy `let`.

With this being said, a **block level scope** in JavaScript most definitely exists, yet how may we access it?

Take for example:

```
var arr = [
    {
        label: "x"
    },
    {
        label: "y"
    },
    {
        label: "z"
    },
];

var randIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if(i === randIdx)
        arr[i].value = true;
    else
        arr[i].value = false;
}

function foo()
{
    if(arr[0] || arr[1] || arr[2])
    {
        alert((\*passing argument*\).label);
    }
}

foo();
```

It must be possible to access the **block scope** of the current `if` statement and retrieve the passing parameter of the given expression! **Block level scope** does exist, so why can't I tinker with it!

Thanks!

Comment: No. But you can easily assign the result of the condition to a variable first.

Comment: Well yea, of course I could @FelixKling, but that's not the point. I'm not trying to solve an issue of assigning a variable, I am asking a question.

Comment: Sure, but as I said, what you want is not possible, so you'd have to look for something that comes as close as possible to what you want (or just let it be). I just think it's more valuable to point out alternatives than just simply say "no"... don't you think?

Comment: @FelixKling Woah woah, relax bud. lol. I was asking if it is possible, not for what is close to doing it. A "Yes" could use an explanation, but a "No" is just fine as a "No." I know how to work my way around, and that's not what I'm asking. --Let it be-- :) Or we can go about editing our comments to mess up the time-line, but yes, good point. Its just that you sounded salty...

Comment: OK. Then simply ignore the alternative suggestions but let future readers profit from them :)

Comment: @WebWanderer Probably, your edit was too radical. You can consider asking a new question instead. Then, someone who knows execution contexts and variable bindings (I don't know much) could explain it better.

Comment: @Oriol this was my initial question, just worded horribly becuase I was in a hurry. If you remember my content from before, you should recognize that the ending question and last block of code do not actually differ much differently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The [`if` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5) is defined as

> The production *IfStatement* : `if` `(` *Expression* `)` *Statement*
>   is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *exprRef* be the result of evaluating *Expression*.
> 2. If [ToBoolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2)([GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*exprRef*)) is **false**, return (normal, empty, empty).
> 3. Return the result of evaluating *Statement*.

As you can see, the result of GetValue(*exprRef*) is not stored anywhere, so you can't retrieve it later.

Instead, consider assigning the condition expression to a variable:

```js
var myVar;
if(myVar = SomeFunction()) {
    myVar; // value returned by `SomeFunction`
}
```

```js
var myVar;
if(myVar = (x || y || z)) { // Parentheses added for clarity
    myVar; // `x`, `y` or `z`
}
```

Comment: Ehhh... thats definately a fitting answer but its still... i don't know... not what I was looking for. I want access to the argument from within the statement by a reserved word or something. Just like `arguments` within a function with no stated parameters.

Comment: @WebWanderer: If you really want that, then you have to create your own JS dialect (which compiles to JS). But is it possible in "plain" JS? No.

Comment: Note that this is bad practice especially the first example since it's very easy for future maintainers to misconstrue this as a bug and replace `=` with `==`. If you must do this leave a comment. But if you're leaving a comment anyway, might as well do it the more usual way - much less typing

Comment: True @slebetman and interesting idea FelixKling, but I'm still going to keep my hopes up. I run into people all of the time that know wierd things about languages that no one else thought of. I'll leave this question up for a while before excepting no for an answer. The possibilities are too awesome for me to not have high hopes about it.

Comment: Don't keep your hopes up too long. Between me and FelixKing, you have 99% of all javascript knowledge. If Bergi comments then you have pretty much 100%

Comment: Very nice edit, and somewhat sadening, yet thank you! And if that is true @slebetman, then I am glad I found you guys. I'd like to think that I know about 99% of JavaScript knowledge myself. I am mostly puzzled at the idea of the `let` statement where, within an `if` statement, only retains block level scope. In this sense, how could there be no way to access said block level scope in javascript. I plan to edit my question.

Comment: @WebWanderer Note that [`let`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations) is introduced by ECMAScript 6, which is still a draft. It binds the variables to the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment (see [Execution Contexts](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-execution-contexts)). That doesn't affect the [`if` statement](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-if-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation), though.

Comment: There is my answer. Thank you.